# Class prefix as selector for each function

Tags: class, selector, prefix, jquery

I am able to do this using an ID prefix as the selector, but I need to be able to do it with classes instead. It's an each function for opening up different modal windows on the same page. I need to avoid using ID names because I have some modal windows that will have multiple links on the same page, and when using IDs, only the first link will work.

So here's the function as it works with IDs:

```
$('div[id^=ssfamodal-help-]').each(function() {
    var sfx = this.id,
        mdl = $(this),
        lnk = $('.link-' + sfx),
        cls = $('.ssfamodal-close'),
        con = $('.ssfamodal-content');

    lnk.click(function(){
        mdl.show();
    });
    cls.click(function(){
        mdl.hide();
    });
    mdl.click(function() {
        mdl.hide();
    });
    con.click(function() {
        return false;
    });
});
```

and I'm trying to change it to classes instead, like:

```
   $('div[class^=ssfamodal-help-]').each(function() {
        var sfx = this.attr('class'),
        etc.
```

But I cannot get it to work without using IDs. Is it possible?

*EDIT* Fixed error with semi-colon at end of Vars, and updated Fiddle with the fix. Still not working though.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xAssR/50/)

** UPDATE **

To be clearer, I need to be able to refer to the same modal more than once on the same page. E.g.:

MODAL 1

MODAL 2

MODAL 3

MODAL 4

LINK TO MODAL 1

LINK TO MODAL 2

LINK TO MODAL 3

LINK TO MODAL 4

OTHER STUFF

LINK TO MODAL 1

LINK TO MODAL 4

LINK TO MODAL 3

OTHER STUFF

LINK TO MODAL 2

ETC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using *classes* get rid of the `ID` habit :

> className1, className2, className3 ... etc

simply use

> className

HTML:

```
<div class="ssfamodal-help-base ssfamodal-backdrop">
    <div id="help-content" class="ssfamodal-content">
        <span class="ssfamodal-close">[x]</span>
        Howdy
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ssfamodal-help-base ssfamodal-backdrop">
    <div id="help-content" class="ssfamodal-content">
        <span class="ssfamodal-close">[x]</span>
        Howdy Ho
    </div>
</div>

<span class="link-ssfamodal-help-base">One</span>
<span class="link-ssfamodal-help-base">Two</span>
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/xAssR/57/)

```
var $btn = $('.link-ssfamodal-help-base'),
    $mod = $('.ssfamodal-help-base'),
    $X   = $('.ssfamodal-close');

$btn.click(function(i) {
  var i = $('[class^="link-"]').index(this); // all .link-** but get the index of this!
  // Why that?! cause if you only do:
  // var i = $('.link-ssfamodal-help-base').index();
  // you'll get // 2
  // cause that element, inside a parent is the 3rd element
  // but retargeting it's index using $('className').index(this);
  // you'll get the correct index for that class name!

  $('.ssfamodal-help-base').eq(i).show()     // Show the referenced element by .eq()
  .siblings('.ssfamodal-help-base').hide();  // hide all other elements (with same class)

});
$X.click(function(){
   $(this).closest('.ssfamodal-help-base').hide();
});
```

<sub>**From the DOCS:**

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

http://api.jquery.com/index/

http://api.jquery.com/closest/</sub>

Here I created a quite basic example on how you can create a jQuery plugin of your own to handle *modals*: http://jsbin.com/ulUPIje/1/edit
feel free to use and abuse.

Comment: That's amazing. I'm still trying to figure out how it tells them apart.

Comment: How are the links pointing to the right divs? Just by the order they appear on the page? If so, that's not going to work for me. Like I said, I'm not sure how this is working.

Comment: @Thom thanks. The trick is to reference a common class (line 6 var `i`) which creates a jQuery elements collection and get the `index` of `this` (which is the JS clicked element) `returns: 0||1 in your case`. Having that number just target the `class` element `.eq()` -> `N` and you're done. Sorry if it sounds hard, I'd be glad to explain more, I just don't know at which point you're with jQ

Comment: This is quite awesome and you deserve props, but as I said, I need to have multiple links on the page to the same modal. I could have been clearer:

Modal 1
Modal 2
Modal 3

Link to 1
Link to 2
Link to 3
Link to 1

A coarse way of displaying what I mean, but there it is.

Comment: @Thom, *same modal* ? I see 2 modal elements, if you need only one there's a quite cool way to have only one and dynamically fill the content! :)

Comment: I am trying to keep the code to a minimum here, but I have about 20 modals, and I need to be able to link to a few of them more than once. Maybe your other suggestion will work as a solution.

Comment: @Thom if you're interested about that solution would you give me the time to setup a basic example? It's quite awesome

Comment: Absolutely. That'd be great!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that class attributes can consist of many classes, rather than IDs which only have one value. One solution, which isn't exactly clean, but seems to work is the following.

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) 
        if (classes[i].indexOf('ssfamodal-help-') == 0)
            return true;
    return false;
}).each(function() {
    // code
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xAssR/49/)**

---

Or, equivalently

```
$('div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/).some(function (e) {
        return e.indexOf('ssfamodal-help-') == 0;
    });
}).each(function() {
    // code
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xAssR/55/)**

Comment: Thanks. Your fiddle link links to my original though. Did you mean to link to a new one?

Comment: Thanks again. That doesn't seem to be working in the fiddle you linked. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

If there is one-to-one relationship between the  modal helps and the modal links which it appears there is...can simplfy needing to match class values by ***using indexing***.

For this reason you don't need unique class names, rather they just overcomplicate things. Following assumes classes stay unique however

```
var $helps=$('div[id^=ssfamodal-help-]');
var $help_links=$('div[id^=link-ssfamodal-help-]');

$help_links.click(function(){
    var linkIndex= $help_links.index(this);
    $helps.hide().eq( linkIndex ).show();
});
 /* not sure if this is what's wanted, but appeared original code had it*/
 $helps.click(function(){
      $(this).hide()
 })

/* close buttons using traverse*/
$('.ssfamodal-close').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('div[id^=ssfamodal-help-]' ).hide();
});
```

Also believe that this code is a little more readable than original apporach

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xAssR/58/)**</kbd>

Comment: I like this, but this is what I need to be able to do:


<span class="link-ssfamodal-help-base" style="cursor:pointer;">One</span>
<span class="link-ssfamodal-help-base2" style="cursor:pointer;">Two</span>
<span class="link-ssfamodal-help-base" style="cursor:pointer;">One</span>

Comment: sure would have been nice to list full requirements at start....non working code is not a substitute for solid explanation of what code is expected to do  - in full. Your html structure can be improved...and code simplified based on new requiremets

Comment: Excuse me, but I was still pretty clear at the outset. And I quote: " I need to avoid using ID names because I have some modal windows that will have multiple links on the same page, and when using IDs, only the first link will work. "

Comment: ok..my bad...was following oversimplified demo. Bare in mind...not always easy to pick up where code and text differ

Comment: No worries! :) I'll take the blame for the demo being oversimplified. Always trying to find the right balance between TMI and too little.

Comment: all you need is a protocol such as using `data-` attributes to match links to modals. Depending on display data structure, could put all the data in an array and really make it easy with one modal

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking at that for a solution. :)

Comment: Just need to figure out how to do the function then, to call the modal with the data-target.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 $('div[class^=ssfamodal-help-]').each(function() {


     var sfx = $(this).attr('class');

         console.log(sfx); 
         /*console log:
           ssfamodal-help-base ssfamodal-backdrop
           ssfamodal-help-base2 ssfamodal-backdrop
         */

 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xAssR/51/

Comment: can't pass those classes to `lnk` selector due to the space between them. Makes the `lnk` selector invalid

Answer (score 0):

why don't you write like

```
$('div.classname').each(function() {

// you can write your desired code here
        var sfx = this.attr('class');
        var aa= this.attr('id');
});
```

or

```
$('.classname').each(function() {
// you can write your desired code here
        var sfx = this.attr('class');
        var aa= this.attr('id');
});
```

where classname is the name of the class used for the div in html

Thanks.